# Не полностью переведено сообщение о закрытии в ревизиях

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, локализация, нет-в-transifex

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/477480/revisions

> Сообщение закрыто по причине «копия» участником Nick Volynkin, VenZell, Nofate♦ of
>
> - Bitrix, Инфоблок, тип свойства “привязка к раpделам инфоблока”
> - Информационные блоки в Bitrix, тип данных “привязка к разделам”

Что за `of`?

Comment: Похоже, это "duplicate of.."

Comment: Ищу уже 20 минут, ну и задачку вы задали  )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну как, за час удалось найти?

Comment: пока что отложил, ещё вернусь. Там вроде есть похожие строки, но откуда "of" — неясно.

Comment: А вдруг кто-то захардкодил? :D

Comment: да там просто адовые шаблоны ))

Comment: а хотя, возможно и такое.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, неужели на это бы раньше никто не наткнулся?

Comment: вспомнил, что баги связанные с хардкодом уже были. Цвета на знаках были захардкожены, на всех сайтах было Gold, Silver, Bronze

Comment: @NickVolynkin, но ведь сайты на других языках уже давно есть - неужели на них никто бы захардкоженные строки не заметил?

Comment: yep. [Нет строки для перевода "цвета" знака](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1706)